# Possible to add two authors with same name, using Co-Authors Plus in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Working on a large content base in WordPress, with the Co-Authors Plus plug-in installed.  Several thousand authors.  A new author needs to be added using the Guest Author functionality provided by the Co-Authors Plus plugin for WordPress, already enabled and successfully in use in our theme.

The new author wants his name spelled exactly as an existing author with the same name.  Attempting to create the author record results in an error, wherein the plugin balks at the duplicate.

We only care about the Display Name - the slugs can be different, even have a number on the end.  However, we can't use different fields than we already do, because we can't make the case for changing the front-end code just based on this error/case.

Has anyone had any luck with this, whether through a straightforward and sensible change in the plugin, a different method of data entry, or anything that's not too... "hackish"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been tinkering on and off for a couple days and arrived at a solution, although it's not ideal, that allows me to end up with multiple authors that have the same name.

In short, WordPress wants the new author's slug to be different than the first.  Once that criterion is met and the record has been created, it appears I can do whatever I want with the Display Name on subsequent edits.  The slug is generated automatically from the Display Name when the Guest Author record is created, so the trick is, well, to trick WordPress temporarily.

I followed these steps:

1. Choose a Display Name for the new author that will result in the creation of a slug you find acceptable.  For example, if the original author's Display Name is `John Smith` (with a slug of `john-smith`), I used `John Smith 2` as the Display Name for the new author.
2. Save the new author - in my example, the slug created upon saving was `john-smith-2`.
3. Now the new author can be edited - I changed the author's Display Name back to `John Smith` and saved without a problem or error.

Note that the slug, once created, cannot easily be changed, and in my case remained `john-smith-2` - so make sure when you're creating the new author with the same name as an existing one that the slug that will be created from the temporary Display Name is something you can live with and, if possible, fits a pattern or system that you can use if you encounter this problem again in the future.